# How do I write a SQL query that finds the frequent customers for a business in this data model?

Tags: sql

My model is along the lines of the following:

- A business has N locations.
- A location has N transactions.
- Each transaction has a customer.
- Each transaction belongs to a transaction group.

How do I write a query that **finds all the customers who have at least K transaction groups at a particular business, where K is an integer**? (I want the result to contain a given customer no more than once.)

Comment: Its easier to post table structure in the future.  I had to pencil in your tables just to get an idea what you were after.

Comment: @JonH: Apologies for being less than clear. I'll be more explicit next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `having`!

```
select
    c.CustomerID,
    count(distinct tg.TransactionGroupID) as GroupCount
from
    Customers c
    inner join Transaction t on
        c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
    inner join Location l on
        t.LocationID = l.LocationID
    inner join Business b on
        l.BusinessID = b.BusinessID
    inner join TransactionGroup tg on
        t.TransactionGroupID = tg.TransactionGroupID
where
    b.BusinessName = 'Some business'
group by c.CustomerID
having count(distinct tg.TransactionGroupID) > 4
```

If you don't need transaction group information, you can just join to the transaction table and forego the second join.

And I used "4" here, but feel free to use a parameter or another integer that suits your fancy.

Comment: This doesn't seem to reference the businesses. Won't this get all the transactions no matter what business they're at?

Comment: Added the join to business for you.

Comment: +1 I like this because I format and alias in the same way, good job!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Customerid
From Transaction t
INNER JOIN TransactionGroup tg
    ON t.transactionid = tg.transactionid
GROUP BY Customerid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionGroup) => @TransactionCountDesired
```

This is the gist, you may need to expand the `JOIN`s further.

As long as you `GROUP BY` customer and have a `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` for your `HAVING` check on the transactiongroup count you won't have any dupes to deal with.